# Wy does downstream pipelines in gitlab-ci does not work as normal pipelines?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I createed Downstream pipelines dynamically and it works fine. But inside the scipts of the child pipelines mvn is not available anymore. My is this?

So as example in the build stage of the parent pipeline:

```
script:
  - mvn --veriosn
```

prints out:

> Apache Maven 3.8.6
> Maven home: /opt/maven
> Java version: 17.0.2, ...

but in the childpipeline it is:

> mvn: command not found

Comment: How are you running the jobs?
Is the same runner assigned to both the parent and child pipelines?
If you are using containers, what images do you use for the downstream and the parent pipeline?

Comment: yes this is it. I forget to define an image in the child pipeline. Thank you